# How much fat should be added to venison when making sausage?

Tags: meat, fat, sausages, venison

I'm making a venison sausage using the front shoulder of the animal.  It appears to be a very lean meat; how much pork belly should I add to the grind?

Comment: What kind of sausage are you intending to make? Common sausages have a fat content in the range of 0 to 50%, making it hard to give you a general advise. Depending on the amount of fat in your pork belly, even that alone may make a rather lean sausage.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Rhulman recommends 3 parts meat to one part fat when making sausage.